# TextView not appearing in ListView with Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` that I'm trying to populate using an `ArrayAdapter` (custom adapter class). The problem is that the `TextView` that I have made inside of the `list_item.xml` is not appearing. This is strange because in this xml I also created an `ImageView` and that *is* showing up. Here is my code:

**FontList.java**

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

ArrayList<String> fontList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("fonts.txt")));

      String line = br.readLine();
      while (line != null) {
            fontList.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();
      }
      br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.fontTextView, fontList);        
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
int textViewResourceId;
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> fontList) {

    super(context, layoutResourceId,textViewResourceId, fontList);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = fontList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater(); 
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);


    String item = data.get(position);
    ImageView ib = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.alreadyDownloaded);
    TextView textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.fontTextView);

    if (item.equals("Aleo") ){ //this is working properly so the arraylist is populated
        ib.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }    

    return row;
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fontTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/alreadyDownloaded"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_accept" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know why the `fontTextView` isnt showing up? The rest of the `ListView` seems fine. The only problem is there is no text.

Comment: Have you tried using `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead of 
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for your ImageView and TextView?

Answer (score 3):

This is because your custom ArrayAdatper will set the default font color to white, and if your background color is also white, you will not actually see the text.

Try changing either the background color or font color like this in your .xml file. You can change your background color like this.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/sample"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#028dbe"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:maxLines="5"/>
```

Comment: tried everything nothing worked until I found this gem hidden here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you did not call `setText` in your `getView` method.

```
TextView textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.fontTextView);
textView.setText(data.get(position));
```

One way to make sure your `TextView` exists is to apply a background color to the `TextView`, so that you can know the `TextView` actually exists and is not hidden/push away/whatever by your layout or other elements.